# How to initialize numpy.ndarray as base class

Tags: python, numpy

I want to subclass numpy.ndarray to customize some behaviour. As the first step, I try out creating my own class as below. But I haven't ever got the initialisation right. Below I initalise my class with [1.,2.] and expect the line "print a" would return me [1.,2.]. But it always returns me [[some_random_number, some_random_number]]. So the dimensions are wrong and the assignment of initial values failed. Please help. I can't figure it out.

```
import numpy as np

class imarray(np.ndarray):
  def __init__(self, d):
      data = np.asarray(d)
      super(imarray, self).__init__((data.size,), dtype=data.dtype, buffer=data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  a = imarray([1.,2.])
  print a
```

Comment: If you haven't already, check out  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html